# How do I retrieve the schema fields that pyarrow has inferred from the Hive partitioning of a Dataset?

Tags: dataset, pyarrow, hive-partitions

Once I've loaded a a hive-partitioned Dataset, how do I retrieve the fields that pyarrow has inferred as being the partitioning fields?
I know I can ask that to a `Fragment` (by using the fragment's `partition_expression`) but I can't find a way to ask a Dataset.

Comment: Of course I could take the first fragment and ask it its `partition_expression`, but that doesn't sound too elegant to me...